# How to register middleware in Kernel in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have created this middleware which I want to use for domain and subdomains (myapp.com, comany1.myapp.com) routing in multi-company application:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use App\Models\Organization\OrgCompany;
use Closure;

class VerifyAppDomain
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->get('domain_name', $this->getBaseDomain());

        $company = OrgCompany::where('subdomain', $subdomain)->firstOrFail();

        $request->session()->put('subdomain', $company);

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function getBaseDomain()
    {
        return config('myconfig.default_domain_name', 'myapp');
    }
}
```

`route/web.php`

```php
Route::domain('myapp')->group(['middleware' => ['veryfy_app_domain']], function () {
    
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/' . $defaultDomain], function () {
        Route::get('/', function ($id) {
               //
        });     
    });

});
```

I have all these in kernel:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
 
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [

];

protected $middlewarePriority = [

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to write and register a middleware is described inside the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#introduction).

For your `VerifyAppDomain` middleware you should go to `app/Http/Kernel.php` file and check the `protected $middlewareGroups` property.

I suppose you want this middleware run for each request, so you could add it to the `web` group. That would mean that you do not need to specify this middlware separately in your `routes.php` file. It would automatically be applied to all routes that use the `web` middleware.

If you don't want to have this automatically applied, use the `$routeMiddelware` property.

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //.. others
    'verify_app_domain' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyAppDomain::class,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new route middleware and add it to the `$routeMiddleware` array. Then you can apply it to your route groups.

```php
protected $routeMiddleware  = [
    'verify_app_domain' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyAppDomain::class
];
```